# how to update record in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Collection

```
'message':[{ 
   'records':[{
    'text':'aaa in stack overflow'
  }]
 }]   

db.collection('message').find().forEach(function(err,doc) {
    doc.records.forEach(function(link){
        var text = link.text.replace('aaa', 'bbb');
        db.collection('message').updateOne({_id: doc._id}, { '$set': { 'text': text } });
    });
});
```

I am getting TypeError: Property 'collection' of object rocking is not a function.

What I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve here with some sample documents that show your collection structure?

Comment: @chridam added collection structure, i am not able to get collection object

Comment: Why i am getting this error Property 'collection' of object rocking is not a function.

Comment: what is this object rocking?

Comment: In your update, is the "message" field (array) also part of the document structure? Can you show what the result is when you do a `db.getCollection('message').findOne()` query? If it's a mongo shell query then the error is as a result of this statement `db.collection('message').find()` which should be `db.getCollection('message').find()` or just `db.message.find()`.

Comment: @chridam db.message.find did the trick thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
db.collection('message').find().forEach(function(err,doc) {
    doc.records.forEach(function(link){
        link.text = link.text.replace('aaa', 'bbb');
        link.save();
    });
});
```

It will update the property and will call save();